# Joomla Plugin cant seem to access params through module code Joomla 1.7 help please

Tags: php, joomla

I am loading a module via a plugin using shortcode for jooolma however im running into a problem im loading the module via the render method this is my plugin code

```
    defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

    add_shortcode("mygallery", "sc_mygallery");
    function sc_mygallery($atts, $content = null) {
      extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "galleryid" => 'galleryid=oHg5SJYRHA0',
        "width" => '480',
        "height" => '360',
        "allowfullscreen" => 'true',    
      ), $atts));


    $module_name='mod_eastbelfastpics';
    $moudle_title='East Belfast Gallery!';
    $module = JModuleHelper::getModule($module_name, $module_title); 

    $module->params = array('Gallery' => $galleryid);
    echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module ,$options);


    }
```

But when i come to outputting the value of Gallery i just get no output what is the problem this is my front end code

```
    <?php
    defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

    $items = $params->get('items', 1);
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "SELECT * from jos_eastbelfastpagegallery_images";
    $db->setQuery( $query, 0 , $items );
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    $galleryid= $params->get('Gallery');
     ?>

    this is content comming from a module form a content plugin ;-)

    <?php echo $galleryid;?>
```

Comment: dont define your actual database prefix. Instead use `#__eastbelfastpagegallery_images`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$options is not defined.

Define $options with suitable parameters you want to pass while rendering your module.